# Trying to Bind a Nested Property Model to a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

My DataGrid contains 2 columns of ComboBox. The easy way is to use a `List<string>` but since I require extra functionality (the ability to dynamically disable some drop down menu items) my code behind uses nested properties: the top-level for the DataGrid and the lower-level for the ComboBox.

See relevant code below (in different attempts and variations):

Left Column XAML:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header=" Left Column ">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SteelThickness, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" SelectedItem="{Binding LeftValues, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Right Column XAML:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header=" Right Column ">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Caliber, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Thickness" SelectedItem="{Binding Thickness, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged">
                <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Enabled}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

GridModel.cs:

```
public class GridModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    public int Item { get; set; }

    private string _LeftValues;
    public string LeftValues
    {
        get
        {
            return _LeftValues;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_LeftValues != value)
            {
                _LeftValues = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("LeftValues");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _RightValues;
    public string RightValues
    {
        get
        {
            return _RightValues;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_RightValues != value)
            {
                _RightValues = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("RightValues");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main:

```
public List<string> SteelThickness { get; set; }
public List<Selectable> Caliber { get; set; }
public List<GridModel> content4VisualGrid = new List<GridModel>();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    SteelThickness = new List<string> { "0.3750", "0.4375", "0.5000", "0.6250", "0.7500", "0.8650", "1.0000" };

    Caliber = new List<Selectable> { new Selectable("0.3750"), 
                                        new Selectable("0.4375"), 
                                        new Selectable("0.5000"), 
                                        new Selectable("0.6250"), 
                                        new Selectable("0.7500"), 
                                        new Selectable("0.8650"), 
                                        new Selectable("1.0001") };
```

Another, better version of GridModel.cs:

```
public class GridModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    public int Item { get; set; }

    public string LeftValue { get; set; }

    private Selectable _Selectable;
    public  Selectable Selectable
    {
        get
        {
            return _Selectable;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Selectable != value)
            {
                _Selectable = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Selectable");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Selectable.cs:

```
public class Selectable : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private string _Thickness;
    public  string  Thickness
    {
        get
        {
            return _Thickness;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Thickness != value)
            {
                _Thickness = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Thickness");
            }
        }
    }

    private bool _Enabled;
    public  bool  Enabled
    {
        get
        {
            return _Enabled;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Enabled != value)
            {
                _Enabled = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Enabled");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what the app looks like: http://patriot.net/~ramon/misc/DataGridTemplateColumn.png

Comment: This is the complete source code (Zipped MSVS Solution). All files are text: http://patriot.net/~ramon/misc/Minimal-Version.zip

Comment: In your haste to display your situation you forgot to ask your question, what do you want?

Comment: Thanks, Ronan! The question is in the Subject line: I want to successfully bind the nested property "Thickness" to the ComboBox column(s) of the DataGrid. I have tried many unsuccessful experiments.

Comment: My Left Column binds fine BUT an `Enabled` property is not provided. My Right Column does not bind, but it provides an `Enabled` property.

Comment: Note: For those interested, the problem is much closer to being solved. I intend to re-post what I have so far.

Answer (score 1):

This code looks familiar to me. Have I maybe answered your question on msdn forums lol?

However, when you set Binding between SelectedItem and a property, the Binding will not search for the property inside Selectable class but you are trying to do that. Its why binding in right column keeps beaking. To put it in simple words: To look up for a property inside selected item and to use the property for binding to ComboBox.SelectedItem is like looking up inside itself which logically doesnt make any sense lol. Read the sentence again and you will notice there is not chance it will ever work :)

On the other side Binding between SelectedItem and LeftValues will work because GridModel is the owner class of each row.

I remember your code from msdn. You really made a mess in design. You don't have a proper ViewModel.

I suggest you to first create few very simple examples to understand MVVM and WPF's hierarchical thinking.

In DataGrid you have GridModel is owner of each row. Inside a row you have ComboBox with SteelThickness as ItemsSource. To put all this in WPF's hierarchical thinking words: GridModel class is parent of SteelThickness. One SteelTickness is for WPF System a child of one GridModel instance.

Here are few links for good understanding of MVVM Pattern:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36545/WPF-MVVM-Model-View-View-Model-Simplified

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

Comment: "You really made a mess in design. You don't have a proper ViewModel." That is by design. What I did was to take bits & pieces that I found on the Internet, paste them together, so it is small wonder that I ended up with the Frankenstein monster :-)

Comment: That is what I ment, you combined those pieces in a messy way lol. Anyways I posted you on msdn how to do that enabling thing. Check it out :)

Comment: In my *many* searches I did bump into the MVVM approach, but for some reason concluded that it was not the correct one for my requirements. I guess I was wrong. I will read those 2 articles.

Comment: "SelectedItem is like looking up inside itself which logically doesnt make any sense" What you saw is just one of *many* attempts, I have tried with every possible combination I can think of. Have about a dozen versions (generations) and fiddle with each. Still, can't find the magic combination. :-(

Comment: Allow me to repost this comment, from above: "My Left Column binds fine BUT an Enabled property is not provided. My Right Column does not bind, but it provides an Enabled property." IOW: Both columns are symmetrical and should be identical. The user may decide to select the combo boxes in reverse order. If I use the simpler (left column) approach, I lose the "Enabled" flag!

Comment: Those are nice requirements but lets not turn this into begging for code lol. Work on having a ViewModel first before solving anything else. Create a class for ViewModel. ViewModel shall hold a list of rows. A row is gonna be of type GridModel as I can see. Inside each row you will have a ComboBox so to have a proper data design you should place that list of Caliber (which is later gonna serve as ItemsSource for each ComboBox) inside the GridModel. Rows will have ComboBoxes -> GridModel will have list of Caliber. See now how is proper ViewModel design being achieved? :) Check those links out.